# Spring MVC - Hibernate Validation Group with Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

We are using Spring Data JPA in our application and we are validating the entities that are being saved to the database using Hibernate Validator. As per the Hibernate Validator documentation, there is a feature to provide validation groups to validate few properties of the entity before saving.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups

Now, when it comes to usage of these validators in Spring, the only way I could find is using them within controllers using the `@Validated` annotation to validate the input.

We have a requirement where we are calling `Repository.save()` by passing the entity and we need to provide the validation group to validate only few items.